# Return A2 when D2 is found in an array

Tags: arrays, excel

Data is being entered into `Sheet 1`, `"Commercial Projects"`

`Sheet 2`, `"Bore"` is where I want data pulled to.

I've been entering my formula as an array.

For instance...

In `A2` of the `"Bore"` sheet, I would like to return the value from `A2` on the `"Commercial Projects"` sheet, given that `D2` on `"Commercial Projects"` is not blank.  However, if `D2` is blank, I would like to return the value in `column A` for the next instance where the value in `column D` is not blank.

It's really hard to describe, so here's the formula I've been working with.  The problem is that for some reason, after the last occurrence where `column D` is not blank, I am still getting the value of `column A`.

`{=IF(IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Commercial Projects'!$A$2:$AC$101,SMALL(IF('Commercial Projects'!$A$2:$AC$101>0,ROW($A$2:$A$101)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX('Commercial Projects'!$A$2:$AC$101,SMALL(IF('Commercial Projects'!$D$2:$D$101>0,ROW('Commercial Projects'!$A$2:$A$101)),ROW(1:1)),1))="","",INDEX('Commercial Projects'!$A$2:$AC$101,SMALL(IF('Commercial Projects'!$D$2:$D$101>0,ROW('Commercial Projects'!$A$2:$A$101)),ROW(1:1)),1))}`

Comment: Are you using R1C1 Reference Style under options?

For example, we see a number of: ROW(1:1)
Which would give you $A$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(OFFSET('Commercial Projects'!A2,0,3)="",INDEX('Commercial Projects'!A2:A101,MATCH(1,IF('Commercial Projects'!D2:D101<>0,IF('Commercial Projects'!D2:D101<>"",1)),0)),'Commercial Projects'!A2)
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down to suit.